# R creating list

Tags: r, list, r-caret

What does `Trainsetb` over here signify? I don't think it is the list name, but haven't been able to understand what it specifies or what is it's purpose.

```
> z=as.integer(4,5, 6)
> class(z)
[1] "integer"
> a=list(z)
> class(a)
[1] "list"
> b=list(Trainsetb = z)
> class(b)
[1] "list"
> names(b)
[1] "Trainsetb"
> names(a)
NULL
> a
[[1]]
[1] 4

> b
$Trainsetb
[1] 4
> b$Trainsetb
[1] 4
> Trainsetb
Error: object 'Trainsetb' not found
```

I am learning data mining using the [book](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/). I am using *caret* package `train` function. Within `train` function there is the `trainControl` argument and it is defined as below:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV",
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     index = list(TrainSet = pre2008),
                     savePredictions = TRUE)
```

I want to know why the author hasn't defined index as `index = list(pre2008)`.

Answer (score 3):

You define what `Trainsetb` means with `b=list(Trainsetb = z)`. See `?list` for details on list syntax: this is an example of defining a list with `tag = value`.

You can now access the value that corresponds to `Trainsetb` in the list using `b$Trainsetb` or `b[["Trainsetb"]]`.

The convenience of accessing this later on is probably why the author used a tag when making the list.

Comment: `pre2008` is a vector of integers. There is only one "resample" being used here. In most cases, we would have a set of resamples that are represented by a few different vectors of integers and we need a way to pass in several sets of vectors (which may not have the same length). A list is the most natural way of doing this.